# How to block a line using NHibernate and Firebird using Pessimistic Lock?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, firebird2.5

**Requirement:**
I'm using NHibernate 3.x with Firebird 2.5 and I'm trying to lock a table "Config" row using Pessimistic Lock.

**Code:**
    session.Refresh(config, LockMode.Upgrade);
    config.Count += 1;
    session.SaveOrUpdate(config);

**Problem:**
The selected line is not being locked properly, so N apps can update the same line at the same time.

The code generated by NHibernate is:
    SELECT ... FROM Config WHERE Id=? FOR UPDATE

When I need to lock a line manually I use the clause below for Firebird:
    SELECT ... FROM Config WHERE Id=? WITH LOCK

So, how to block a line using NHibernate and Firebird using Pessimistic Lock?

Comment: You will probably need to provide an alternative dialect that will make NHibernate use `WITH LOCK` instead of `FOR UPDATE`. Another option would be to issue an update with side effects (eg `UPDATE SET field = field WHERE ID = x` This will lock the row as well.